# Finding Max() values via foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, aggregate-functions

Consider this database structure:

```
 __________                 __________
| Trucks   |               | Mileage  |
|__________|__________     |__________|________________________
| ID    | DRIVER      |    | TRUCK_ID  | MILEAGE  | OIL_CHANGE |
|---------------------|    |-----------------------------------|
| 1     | Tony        |    | 1         | 100000     105000     |
| 2     | George      |    | 2         | 6020       10020      |
| 3     | Mary        |    | 3         | 37798      41000      |
|_____________________|    | 3         | 41233      47200      |
                           | 3         | 49000                 |
                           |___________________________________|
```

I want to end up with a result set containing the maximum miles and maximum oil_change for each driver.

```
_________________________________
| 1  | Tony  |  100000 | 105000 |
| 2  | George|  6020   | 10020  |
| 3  | Mary  |  49000  | 47200  |
|_______________________________|
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT t.*, MAX(m.mileage) AS mileage, MAX(m.oil_change) AS oil_change
FROM trucks t
LEFT JOIN mileage m ON t.id = m.truck_id
GROUP BY t.id
```

But this doesn't seem to allow the `MAX` function to work properly. It does not always contain the actual maximum value for `mileage`

Comment: Will it always hold true that the `max(mileage)` is the same record as the `max(oil_change)`?  If not, you could get misleading query results.

Comment: Aha! There's the problem. No it won't. The max mileage and max oil change will always be different rows. What should I do? Could do two separate queries, but where is the fun in that.

Comment: You need to add what you want -- oil change @ max(mileage) or mileage @ max(oil change)?

Comment: I need the maximum values of both columns for each truck.

Comment: How about you add another case or two to highlight your first comment and then list your expected output?

Comment: Why don't you post the desired output? You will most likely get an answer this way.

Comment: There might be something wrong with my database. I'm doing `select max(mileage) from mileage where truck_id = 3` and its returning `37798` ... which is not the max.

Comment: I may be missing something, but it looks like if you add t.Driver to your GROUP BY clause, it will produce the correct output. - http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119679/

Comment: It's not returning the maximum value Jeremy. There are definitely higher mileage values for this driver that it is not returning. Please see above comment.

Comment: @JeremyWiggins: If `ID` is the primary key then I don't think it would change anything, although that change would certainly make the query more complying with the standards.

Comment: I updated my first comment to include a link.  The output looks correct to me, and I added a 3rd row for Mary, so that the max mileage and max oil change would be in different rows.

Comment: @ChrisG.: Believe me or not, I cannot see any problem with your query. It should work. Maybe the issue is connected with something else since you can now see it replicating in much simpler case.

Comment: Very weird. It always manages to get the maximum value for oil_change but not for mileage... Thanks for the help at least. Not really sure why my database isn't responding correctly.

Comment: So, if I have `order by mileage desc` on my db. I get a result set in this order: 9000, 10000,100000. Does this shed any light on the issue? Note: `desc` not a typo.

Comment: @JeremyWiggins: You are correct, the SE Data Explorer *requires* `t.Driver` to be included in `GROUP BY` as its back end is SQL Server. MySQL is unique among many, if not all, RDBMSes in that it allows the so called [‘hidden columns’ in queries with grouping](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html). Long story short, in this particular case, adding `t.Driver` would most probably not affect the results.

Comment: It will also order like this 14300, 1432, 15220

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it! Your mileage column must be defined as a character type, not a numeric type! When than happens, order is done alphabetically, not by value.

You should convert your `mileage` and `oil_change` columns to a numeric type (I'd recommend  `INT` based on the data sample provided).

While you don't convert them, this will work:

```
SELECT t.*, MAX(cast(m.mileage as int)) AS mileage, 
            MAX(cast(m.oil_change as int)) AS oil_change
FROM trucks t
LEFT JOIN mileage m ON t.id = m.truck_id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: Note that mysql will require you to cast as SIGNED or UNSIGNED [integer]

Comment: ANd never under any cicumstances use that horrible mysql group by syntax. Use group by the correct way where all notn aggregates columns are specified. The other can have unfortunate and incorrect results. Of couse select t.* is a SQL antipattern as well.

Comment: @HLGEM Good advice. My answer only focused on getting OPs query to work, by addressing data type issue, since `mileage` is stored as a character data type, thus, aggregate functions were not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The below queries should work for your question.

```
SELECT T.DRIVER,MIN(MILEAGE) AS MIN_MILEAGE,MIN(OIL_CHANGE) AS MIN_OIL_CHANGE
FROM TRUCKS T INNER JOIN MILEAGE M
ON T.ID = M.TRUCK_ID
GROUP BY T.DRIVER;


SELECT T.DRIVER,MAX(MILEAGE) AS MAX_MILEAGE,MAX(OIL_CHANGE) AS MAX_OIL_CHANGE
FROM TRUCKS T INNER JOIN MILEAGE M
ON T.ID = M.TRUCK_ID
GROUP BY T.DRIVER;
```

Regards
Venk

Comment: Guys what do you think about above query?